# changing the threading model of a com component

Tags: c#, com

I am using a COM component/typelib supplied by another programmer. Is there any way to change its threading model by tweaking registry of the machine where it is registered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *possible* that tweaking the registry would change the advertised threading model, although I'd really expect it to be part of the data in the binary itself - but even if it "works" *don't do it*. If a component has been designed, implemented and tested for one threading model, then trying to "just change it" to a different one is a phenomenally bad idea. It's like changing the colour of a fuel cap from green to black and saying "Now I'll put diesel fuel into this petrol engine."

It's possible that it will *appear* to work for a while, but then die horribly - probably at the worst possible time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What are the steps for registry tweaks? I just need to tweak the registry and find out the component is failing only in STA model and inform the component provider

Comment: @logeeks: I really don't know, to be honest - I wouldn't even try it; I'd simply talk with the component provider to start with.